# How to get campaign details using MMC and python ad-words library given ClientID

Tags: python, google-ads-api

Below is my base code for trying to get all campaigns and campaign details from adwords using the python api.  I am using the MCC.  So, if given the customer ID, how do I loop through all campaigns in the account and retrieve all of the campaign settings?

```
import os
import datetime
from adspygoogle.adwords.AdWordsClient import AdWordsClient
from adspygoogle.common import Utils
from pprint import pprint

google_service = 'https://adwords.google.com'
headers = {
      'email': 'test@gmail.com',
      'password': 'test',
      'userAgent': 'Test',
      'developerToken': 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    }


google_service = 'https://adwords.google.com'
api_version = 'v201109'

client = AdWordsClient(headers=headers)
client.use_mcc = True
client.SetDebug=True
client.SetClientCustomerId='11111111111'
campaign_service = client.GetCampaignService(google_service, api_version)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the Python library, but I took a quick look at the examples and found that, strangely enough, the sample code you should start with has been placed into the reporting folder. If you check out the example for [downloading campaign stats](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ads-python/source/browse/trunk/examples/adspygoogle/adwords/v201109/reporting/get_campaign_stats.py), you should be able to work out how to extract what you want.

You'll need to browse through the [CampaignService documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/CampaignService.html) to find the fields you want, and also remember that many of the campaign settings need to be obtained via other services: namely the [CampaignCriterionSerivce](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/CampaignCriterionService.html), [CampaignTargetService](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/CampaignTargetService.html), and [CampaignAdExtensionService](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/CampaignAdExtensionService.html).

If you need any more help, then the best place to ask is the [official AdWords API forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/adwords-api); during office hours you'll usually get a response from the Google AdWords API engineers.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work and is provided as an example from the [Adwords Github repo](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/tree/master/examples/adwords/v201506/account_management). This returns a list of all Client Ids under your MCC account. From there you could write loops to perform certain functions over each Client Id.

```
from googleads import adwords

def DisplayAccountTree(account, accounts, links, depth=0):
  prefix = '-' * depth * 2
  print '%s%s, %s' % (prefix, account['customerId'], account['name'])
  if account['customerId'] in links:
    for child_link in links[account['customerId']]:
      child_account = accounts[child_link['clientCustomerId']]
      DisplayAccountTree(child_account, accounts, links, depth + 1)

def main(client):
  # Initialize appropriate service.
  managed_customer_service = client.GetService(
      'ManagedCustomerService', version='v201506')

  # Construct selector to get all accounts.
  selector = {
      'fields': ['CustomerId', 'Name']
  }
  # Get serviced account graph.
  graph = managed_customer_service.get(selector)
  if 'entries' in graph and graph['entries']:
    # Create map from customerId to parent and child links.
    child_links = {}
    parent_links = {}
    if 'links' in graph:
      for link in graph['links']:
        if link['managerCustomerId'] not in child_links:
          child_links[link['managerCustomerId']] = []
        child_links[link['managerCustomerId']].append(link)
        if link['clientCustomerId'] not in parent_links:
          parent_links[link['clientCustomerId']] = []
        parent_links[link['clientCustomerId']].append(link)
    # Create map from customerID to account and find root account.
    accounts = {}
    root_account = None
    for account in graph['entries']:
      accounts[account['customerId']] = account
      if account['customerId'] not in parent_links:
        root_account = account
    # Display account tree.
    if root_account:
      print 'CustomerId, Name'
      DisplayAccountTree(root_account, accounts, child_links, 0)
    else:
      print 'Unable to determine a root account'
  else:
    print 'No serviced accounts were found'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Initialize client object.
  adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()
  main(adwords_client)
```